# Since Android 6.0 listening to the PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE changes seems to no longer require READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I'm applying Android 6.0 runtime permissions into an app which listens to carrier data connection state changes. I first tried to just remove the READ_PHONE_STATE from the manifest to check where the app requires the permission. To my surprise the app didn't crash at all.

After this I've tried the same installation on two pre 6.0 devices which did actually crash on it. To me it seems like Android 6.0 does no longer require the permission. Is there any way to confirm this?

The line below is the one on which the pre 6.0 devices crashes:

```
tm(TelephonyManager).listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there any way to confirm this?

Yes, this [commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/309b2f63f3265c341f6a43cbca2fb25f9c38109a) removes the request of `READ_PHONE_STATE` when register the event type `LISTEN_CALL_STATE`, `LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY` and `LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE`:

```
Do not enforce PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION to register listener PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION should not be required to register to the following event types:
- PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE
- PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY
- PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE

In case of LISTEN_CALL_STATE, an empty string should be passed instead of incomingNumber, when caller has no PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION.

Bug: 21588537 Change-Id: I5b6d0308924f7e4cd13a983b8e0c9b3a5bbb119b
```

The documentation on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE) was updated and correctly shows that the permission are not required.

If your code doesn't need the permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` for other reason apart from `LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE` you can change your `AndroidManifest.xml` adding `maxSdkVersion` to the `uses-permission`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: Thanks...it'd be nice if they left a note that it STILL requires permission on Android <6.0 as I released an update adding this functionality and had no idea LISTEN_CALL_STATE requires a permission before Marshmallow.

Comment: I should add that specifying `maxSdkVersion` is highly risky, as your app will be uninstalled if the OS is upgraded beyond that version. See (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element)

Comment: @DavidBurström The link you posted is referred to `uses-sdk`, not `uses-permission`. They are two different things.

Comment: Thanks, I misread. It might be worth mentioning that the attribute was added in API level 19, but the documentation does not clarify what that means for older devices. Possibly an up-to-date Google Play on an API level 18 or older device will not list the permission in the installation dialog if it is no longer required on the device OS, but that's pure conjecturing.

Comment: Starting with Android 12, it is required again...
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/reference/compat-framework-changes

Answer (score 1):

There is no special permission listed for `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE` in the official android documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE