# Why does Cordova Plugin Media need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

So, why is cordova-plugin-media adding the READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

I found a commit in Chromium https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/12480009/ that might be related. It seems the MediiaPlayerListener.java dropped the need for READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Can we do the same thing with the cordova plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. It seems cordova plugin media is listening for state changes such as `ringing` or `idle` to mute the audio. These events are sent by the cordova-android platform itself by listening to the PhoneStateListener (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) events.

Apparently, up until Android API 22, the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission was required for this. For API 23, the permission is not required anymore.

Here's an answer on stackoverflow pointing to the commit in Android that changed this. [Since Android 6.0 listening to the PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE changes seems to no longer require READ_PHONE_STATE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433829/since-android-6-0-listening-to-the-phonestatelistener-listen-data-connection-sta)